# How can i pass a url with a unique parameter to a controller method in ajax , along with Route name?

Tags: c#, ajax, url, model-view-controller, routes

I am not able to recognize how can i specify the route name and the parameter to a controller method knowing that my parameter is not "id"

i tried using windows.href.location but didn't really know how to adjust it

this is my ajax method where the Route name is "User" and the required parameter to send is "username"

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

    function getDateString(date) {
    var dateObj = new Date(parseInt(date.substr(6)));
    return dateObj.toDateString();
      }

            $('#myTable').DataTable({
                "ajax": {
                    "url": "/Browse/LoadData2",
                    "type": "GET",
                    "datatype": "json",


                },
                "columnDefs":
                    [{
                        "targets": [0],
                        "visible": false,
                        "searchable": false
                    }],


                "columns": [
                    { "data": "id", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data": "Poster", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data": "Position", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data": "Description", "autoWidth": true },
                    {"data": "Date", "autoWidth": true, "render": function (data){

                       return '<td>'+getDateString(data)+'</td>'; 
                     }
                    },
                    { "data": "Salary", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data": "Contact", "autoWidth": true },
                    {"data": "Training_Center", "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
                            var names = [];
                            var array = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@ViewBag.usernames));
                            for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                                names[i] = array[i];
                            }
                        if (names.includes(data)) {

                                return '<a style="color:#18d26e;" href=' +'@Url.Action("Exists2", "Users","User")?username ='+data+'>Visit Me</a>';

                            }
                            else {
                                return '<td>' + data + '</td>';
                            }


                        }
                    }]

            });
        });
    </script>
```

this is my Route.config

```
                 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection 
              routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = 
        UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
        routes.MapRoute(
        name: "User",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{username}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Users", action = "Exists2" ,username= UrlParameter.Optional },
        constraints: new { username = new UserNameConstraint() }
    );
    }
    public class UserNameConstraint : IRouteConstraint
    {
        public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
        {
            Controllers.UsersController p = new Controllers.UsersController();
            string[] usernames = p.getUsernames();
            // Get the username from the url
            var username = values["username"].ToString().ToLower();
            // Check for a match (assumes case insensitive)
            return usernames.Any(x => x.ToLower() == username);
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated .. thanks!!

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? It is easy to add additional parameters to an action method. Why do you need the UserNameConstraint?

Comment: i managed to send an id instead of username because i am in a rush , i was trying to send the username to a controller method using ajax but it wasn't working and i was getting an HTTP404 error .. I tried setting a Map.Route following a tutorial but it didn't work.